# Mathematica + Numerical Recipes

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, librarylink

the idea of combining Mathematica with the new routines in the 3rd edition of Numerical Recipes (NR) is very interesting. In fact, there is a NR library to Matlab which works very well because not only it allows one to create NR code (in C++) and install it as a function in Matlab, but it also cleverly handles the input and output of data.

Does anyone know anything about this topic? I have asked the NR forum about this and received no answer.

I know MathLink can be used to link C code to Mathematica, but seeing the coding level of it's Matlab counterpart, I wouldn't even dare to try and do this myself.

In my view, the true power of scientific computing is in combining different libraries/platforms, efficiently exploiting their merits and deficits.

Comment: As far as I know there is also NR for Java available. Reading the answer to this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-execute-a-function-in-the-package-from-java) will make it very easy to call those from MMa.

Comment: "... the true power of scientific computing is in combining different libraries/platforms, efficiently exploiting their merits and deficits." Yeah, but only what's valuable. NR contains bad algorithms, I've benchmarked several of them myself. And google a bit for the NR controversy, and have a look at the Criticism section in the wikipedia article. And as a Mathematica user you'll find plenty of NR stuff that's already included in Mathematica.

Comment: Andreas, I agree. No platform is perfect, and the key is in exploiting the good routines of each one. Here is an example: a while ago I was solving the following somewhat general problem: find the local minima of a function starting at some specified point; then change the function slightly and find a new minima starting from the previous point; do this sequel toy a bunch of times. Since we are always close to the min, this Should require only a few function evaluations and thus be quite fast.

Comment: (continuation) I have tried to implement this on Mathematica in many ways but with NR the results are always much faster. The reason, at least for me, is simple: there is almost no overhang on the latter. This is the sort of problems I am interested: comparing platforms and finding the most efficient for each problem.

Comment: @Gabriel: Then show your problem here. Pick the brilliant minds that are in this group. Maybe your Mathematica implementation was wrong or too simplistic, so from the solutions of others you could even learn how to do it better. The minimizers in Mathematica have several different method options, and there's many ways to use them in clever ways you've never seen before. Besides, there's also a few 3rd party optimization packages for Mathematica.

Comment: Sorry Andreas. That is not the point. I am sure you understand that different languages/platforms are better at different types of problems. By combining NR with Mathematica, my goal is to have a unified access to both of them. I am sorry, I don't want to turn this into a programming lenguage's discussion; my question was technical and I appreciate everyone's feedback.

Comment: @GabrielLandi I know this is not what you're after in this question in general, but for solving your concrete problem with mathematica, you might want to check out this [Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize)

Comment: I second @ruebenko's advice to use LibraryLink to make NR functions callable from Mathematica.  Don't be afraid of working with LibraryLink, it's quite easy to use once you get the hang of it.  See [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140869/minimal-effort-method-for-integrating-c-functions-into-mathematica) on different ways to integrate C/C++ functions into Mathematica (exactly what you're asking for).  Since then I use LibraryLink for all similar tasks.

Comment: In fact it's easier to write a LibraryLink interface to any numerical C/C++ functions than a command line interface (because LibraryLink allows exchanging typed data without having to convert to strings, like you do when you use data files).  If I were playing with NR routines, I'd definitely start by writing a LibraryLink interface to them, simply because it's so much easier to experiment using the interactive interface of Mathematica than any other way.  So again: just use LirbaryLink, it's easier than you think!

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs. I'll start working in this right away.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimal effort method for integrating C++ functions into Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/minimal-effort-method-for-integrating-c-functions-into-mathematica)

Comment: I voted to close this question as duplicate because it is essentially asking how to call C or C++ functions from Mathematica.

Comment: Lapack subroutines can be easily integrated using LibraryLink. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/linking-fortran-with-librarylink

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are a couple of thoughts:

1) If you want to link to NR, I suggest using `LibraryLink` since the overhead of `MathLink` may be too much for some applications. (In version 5, I used `MathLink` to link against BLAS [libraries](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4891/) but an overhead was noticeable.)

2) A lot of quite sophisticated, high performance algorithms are already implemented in Mathematica. I'd suggest you try them first. As an arbitrary example (but there are many more), numerical integration is well implemented in Mathematica.

3) If your application area is not represented to your satisfaction (I'd like to hear about that), you might make a question from that here and there may be alternatives. So it might be good if ask for a specific numerical issue you'd like to solve and then see what is already available.

4) Additionally, I am not sure if you are aware of this, there are links to say, BLAS readily available.  The libraries that come with Mathematica are quite optimized. (e.g. Intel's MKL for BLAS)

Comment: +1. Nail on the head. Don't try to fix what's not broken.

Comment: Hi Ruebenko, I appreciate the reply. I have the habit of comparing Mathematica and NR whenever possible and I know some Mathematica libraries are quite optimized. However, the habilitation if easily switching between one and the other is what I ultimately strive. For instance, sometimes I write code using NR and call it from Mathematica using terminal syntax + ReadList, which I know is not very efficient.

Comment: @GabrielLandi, you mention comparison, then using `ReadList` is not going to be efficient in speed and likely memory, Have a look at `LibraryLink` that will improve the interface. Also, I am curious to hear what comes out of your comparison.

Comment: I recently compared `BinaryReadList` to Java `FileInputStream` on large files and found that they are speed-equivalent, and MathLink/JLink data transfer overhead was a minor factor since most of the time was spent on the system I/O calls. Based on this, and the fact that modern Java is speed-equivalent to C, I may expect not much performance boost from using `LibraryLink` vs `BinaryReadList`, except when you have to call the latter in a loop (having loops in C rather than Mathematica can of course make a difference for lightweight records). The usual `ReadList` is much slower, of course.

Comment: Yes, good point `BinaryReadList` should do much better than `ReadList`