# Link ITK with Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, interoperability, image3d

I would like to know if someone has tried to link Mathematica with ITK code (call [ITK](http://www.itk.org/) code in Mathematica)?

Comment: It looks like it's written in C++, so [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8438/134) more general information might be useful.

Comment: It seems you've been looking for something like this for a while: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00252.html  It's the only related post Google gives me.  If you implement it yourself, be sure to let us know!

Comment: From what I can tell ITK is already integreated, run a `WatershedComponents` filter and watch for an ITK process to appear.

Comment: Maybe we should give this a go using [LTemplate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96127/how-to-simplify-writing-librarylink-code/96128#96128) ... I actually wanted to use an ITK filter from Mathematica today, but didn't have time to figure it out.  Never used ITK before.

Comment: Try evaluating ``?Image`ITK`*``.

Answer (score 2):

ITK seems to have already been implemented using MathLink. Watch your processes when you run a `WatershedComponents` filter, you can see an `ITK.exe` process appear. I'm not too familiar with `MathLink` but maybe this very simple starting point can be taken further by people who know how to use `MathLink`.

This is a Windows-centric example:

```
itk = LinkLaunch["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\8.0\\SystemFiles\\\Converters\\Binaries\\Windows\\ITK.exe"]

(*
LinkObject["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \Research\\Mathematica\\8.0\\SystemFiles\\Converters\\Binaries\\\Windows\\ITK.exe", 33, 12] 
*)

LinkRead[itk]

(*
"Begin[\"Image`ITK`\"];"
*)

LinkReadyQ[itk]

(*
True
*)

LinkWrite[itk, 5]
LinkRead[itk]

(*
"Image`ITK::filterr = \"`1` generated code `2`: `3`\";"
*)
```

It would be nice to have the source code of the compiled `ITK` `MathLink` executable. ITK is released under an Apache or BSD license which, I think, means that Wolfram can use the code in a closed source application and not release it as long as they provide a copy of the license.

Comment: It is there:                  FindList[FileNameJoin[{$TopDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
   "TextResources", 
       "AboutBox.nb"}], {"ITK", "Insight"}]     gives                                        {"Cell[\"ITK\", \"LicenseText\",", "Copyright (c) 1999-2003 Insight \
Software Consortium All rights reserved.\\", "* Neither the name of \
the Insight Software Consortium nor the names of its \\"}