# How to simplify writing LibraryLink code?

Tags: librarylink, development

[LibraryLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/Overview.html) is an API for extending Mathematica through C or C++.  It is very fast because it gives direct access to Mathematica's packed array data structure, without even needing to make a copy of the arrays.

Unfortunately, working with LibraryLink involves writing a lot of tedious boilerplate code.

Mathematica 10 introduced managed library expressions, a way to have C-side data structures automatically destroyed when Mathematica no longer keeps a reference to them.  I find this feature useful for almost all non-trivial LibraryLink projects I make, but unfortunately it requires even more boilerplate.

For me, writing all this repetitive code (and looking up how to do it in the documentation) has been the single biggest barrier to starting any LibraryLink project. It just takes too much time.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Folks, **not enough love for this Q / A!**

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I wrote a package to automatically generate all the boilerplate needed for LibraryLink and for managed library expressions based on a *template* that describes a class interface:

- [LTemplate](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate)

#### Here's how it works

- Write a *template* (a Mathematica) expression that describes a C++ class interface
- This template is used to generate LibraryLink-compatible C functions that call the class's member functions, to compile them, and to finally load them
- Instances of the class are created as [managed library expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html#353220453); all the boilerplate code for this is auto-generated
- The package is designed to be embedded into Mathematica applications. This avoids conflicts between different applications using different LTemplate versions.  LTemplate can also be used standalone for experimentation and initial development.

#### Examples

**Note:** *The package comes with a tutorial and many more examples in its `Documentation` subdirectory.*

While LTemplate is designed to be embedded into other applications, for this small example I'll demonstrate interactive standalone use.

```
<< LTemplate`
```

Let us use the system's temporary directory as our working directory for this small example, so we don't leave a lot of mess behind. Skip this to use the current directory instead.

```
SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory]
```

To be able to demonstrate managed library expressions later, we turn off input/output history tracking:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
```

Let's write a small C++ class for calculating the mean and variance of an array:

```
code = "
  #include <LTemplate.h>

  class MeanVariance {
    double m, v;

  public:
    MeanVariance() { mma::print(\"constructor called\"); }
    ~MeanVariance() { mma::print(\"destructor called\"); }

    void compute(mma::RealTensorRef vec) {
        double sum = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0;
        for (mint i=0; i < vec.length(); ++i) {
            sum  += vec[i];
            sum2 += vec[i]*vec[i];
        }
        m = sum / vec.length();
        v = sum2 / vec.length() - m*m;
    }

    double mean() { return m; }
    double variance() { return v; }
  };
  ";

Export["MeanVariance.h", code, "String"]
```

LTemplate functions live in the `mma` C++ namespace.  `mma::RealTensorRef` represents a reference to a Mathematica packed array of `Real`s.  It is just a wrapper for the `MTensor` type.  There may be more than one reference to the same array, so array creation and destruction must still be managed manually.

`RealTensorRef` (an alias for `TensorRef<double>`) has a number of convenience features:

- Linear indexing into the array using the `[ ]` operator.  `RealMatrixRef` and `RealCubeRef` are subclasses of `RealTensorRef`, which additionally allow indexing into 2D or 3D arrays using the `( )` operator.
- Iteration through elements using `begin()` and `end()`. Range-based for loops work, e.g. we could have used `for (auto &x : vec) sum += x;`.

We have three member functions: one for computing both the mean and variance in one go, and two others for retrieving each result.

The class must go in a header file with the same name, `MeanVariance.h` in this case.

Let's write the corresponding template now:

```
template =
  LClass["MeanVariance",
   {
    LFun["compute", {{Real, _, "Constant"}}, "Void"],
    LFun["mean", {}, Real],
    LFun["variance", {}, Real]
   }
  ];
```

We can optionally check that the template has no errors using `ValidTemplateQ[template]`.

Compiling and loading is now as simple as

```
In[]:= CompileTemplate[template]

Current directory is: /private/var/folders/31/l_62jfs110lf0dh7k5n_y2th0000gn/T

Unloading library MeanVariance ...

Generating library code ...

Compiling library code ...

Out[]= "/Users/szhorvat/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/LibraryResources/MacOSX-x86-64/MeanVariance.dylib"
```

and then

```
LoadTemplate[template]
```

The compilation step created a file called `LTemplate-MeanVariance.cpp` in the same directory, the source code of which I attached at the end, for illustration.

We can now create a managed library expression corresponding to this class:

```
obj = Make["MeanVariance"]

During evaluation of In[]: constructor called

(* MeanVariance[1] *)

arr = RandomReal[1, 10];

obj@"compute"[arr]

{obj@"mean"[], obj@"variance"[]}
(* {0.482564, 0.104029} *)
```

We can check the list of live expressions of type `MeanVariance` using

```
LExpressionList["MeanVariance"]
(* {MeanVariance[1]} *)
```

As soon as Mathematica has no more references to this expression, it gets automatically destroyed

```
obj =.

During evaluation of In[]: destructor called

LExpressionList["MeanVariance"]
(* {} *)
```

The reason why we had to use `$HistoryLength = 0` above is to prevent `Out` keeping a reference to the expression.

One practical way to write a Mathematica functions that exposes this functionality is

```
meanVariance[arr_] :=
 Block[{obj = Make[MeanVariance]},
  obj@"compute"[arr];
  {obj@"mean"[], obj@"variance"[]}
 ]
```

As soon as the `Block` finishes, `obj` gets automatically destroyed:

```
meanVariance[arr]

During evaluation of In[]: constructor called

During evaluation of In[]: destructor called

(* {0.618649, 0.033828} *)
```

This is one of those special cases when using `Block` over `Module` may be worth it for performance reasons. (The usual caveats about `Block` apply though.)

Notice that the expression has the form `MeanVariance[1]`.  The integer index `1` is the [`ManagedLibraryExpressionID`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ManagedLibraryExpressionID.html).  The symbol `MeanVariance` is created in the context

```
LClassContext[]
(* "LTemplate`Classes`" *)
```

This context is added to the [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ContextPath.html) when using LTemplate interactively as a standalone package, but not when it's loaded privately by another application.  We can check the usage message of the symbol:

```
?MeanVariance

class MeanVariance:
    Void compute(Constant List<Real, _>)
    Real mean()
    Real variance()
```

---

The package is too large to present fully in a StackExchange post, so if you are interested, download it and read the tutorial, and take a look at the many examples that come with the package!

LTemplate is continually under development, and breaking changes are possible (though unlikely).  However, since the recommended way to deploy it is to embed it fully in the Mathematica application that uses it, this should not be a problem.  I am using LTemplate in the [IGraph/M package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM), which proves its feasibility for use in large projects.

There are additional features such as:

- Multiple related classes in the same template
- Support for additional data types, such as SparseArray, RawArray, Image/Image3D
- Pass another managed library expression to a function, and receive it as object reference on the C++ side (`LExpressionID`)
- Format templates to be human-readable (`FormatTemplate`)
- User-friendly error messages
- Error handling through exceptions (`mma::LibraryError`); unknown exceptions are also caught to prevent killing the kernel when possible.
- Calling `Print` for debugging (also through a C++ streams interface), `massert` macro to replace C's standard `assert` and avoid killing the Mathematica kernel.
- Calling `Message`, setting a symbol to associate standard messages with
- Argument passing and return using MathLink (`LinkObject` passing)
- `mlstream.h` auxiliary header for easier LinkObject-based passing

The documentation isn't complete, but if you have questions, feel free to comment here or email me.

---

#### Questions and limitations

**Can I use plain C instead of C++?** No, LTemplate requires the use of C++.  However, the only C++ feature the end-user programmer must use is creating a basic class.

**Why do I have to create a class?  I only want a few functions.**  I didn't implement free functions due to lack of time and need.  There's no reason why this shouldn't be added.  However, you can always create a single instance of a class, and keep calling functions on it.  The overhead will be minimal according to my measurements.

**Why can't I use underscores in class or function names?** LTemplate currently only supports names that are valid *both* in Mathematica and C++. This excludes underscores and \$ signs (even though *some* C++ compilers support `$` in identifiers).  This also helps avoid name conflicts with auxiliary functions LTemplate generates (which always have underscores).

**How do I write library initialization and cleanup code?** Currently LTemplate doesn't support injecting code into `WolframLibrary_initialize` and `WolframLibrary_uninitialize`.  Initialization code can be called manually from Mathematica. Create a single instance of a special class, put the initialization code in one of its member functions, and call it from Mathematica right after loading the template.  The uninitialization code can go in the destructor of the class. All objects are destroyed when the library is unloaded (e.g. when Mathematica quits).  Warning: when using this method, there's no guarantee about which expression will be destroyed last!  To fix this, initialization/uninitialization support is planned for later.

**Can I create a function that takes an MTensor of unspecified type?**  No, LTemplate requires specifying the data type (but not the rank) of the MTensor.  `{Real, 2}` is a valid type specifier and so is `{Real, _}`.  `{_, _}` is not allowed in LTemplate, even though it's valid in standard LibraryLink.  The same applies to MSparseArrays (`mma::SparseArrayRef`). However, RawArray and Image may be passed without an explicit element-type specification.

**Which LibraryLink features are *not* supported?**

- The numerical type underlying tensors must be explicitly specified. Tensors without explicitly specified types are not supported.  In the future tensors of unspecified types may be handled through C++ templates.
- There's no explicit support for [library callback functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html#894022691) yet, but they can be used by accessing the standard LibraryLink API (function pointers in `mma::libData`).

#### Feedback

Contributions and ideas for improvements are most welcome!  Feel free to email me.  If you find a bug, [file a bug report](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate/issues).

---

Source of `LTemplate-MeanVariance.cpp`:

```c++
#define LTEMPLATE_MMA_VERSION  1120

#include "LTemplate.h"
#include "LTemplateHelpers.h"
#include "MeanVariance.h"


#define LTEMPLATE_MESSAGE_SYMBOL  "LTemplate`LTemplate"

#include "LTemplate.inc"


std::map<mint, MeanVariance *> MeanVariance_collection;

DLLEXPORT void MeanVariance_manager_fun(WolframLibraryData libData, mbool mode, mint id)
{
    if (mode == 0) { // create
      MeanVariance_collection[id] = new MeanVariance();
    } else {  // destroy
      if (MeanVariance_collection.find(id) == MeanVariance_collection.end()) {
        libData->Message("noinst");
        return;
      }
      delete MeanVariance_collection[id];
      MeanVariance_collection.erase(id);
    }
}

extern "C" DLLEXPORT int MeanVariance_get_collection(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument * Args, MArgument Res)
{
    mma::TensorRef<mint> res = mma::detail::get_collection(MeanVariance_collection);
    mma::detail::setTensor<mint>(Res, res);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}


extern "C" DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion()
{
    return 3;
}

extern "C" DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData)
{
    mma::libData = libData;
    {
        int err;
        err = (*libData->registerLibraryExpressionManager)("MeanVariance", MeanVariance_manager_fun);
        if (err != LIBRARY_NO_ERROR) return err;
    }
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

extern "C" DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize(WolframLibraryData libData)
{
    (*libData->unregisterLibraryExpressionManager)("MeanVariance");
    return;
}


extern "C" DLLEXPORT int MeanVariance_compute(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument * Args, MArgument Res)
{
    mma::detail::MOutFlushGuard flushguard;
    const mint id = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    if (MeanVariance_collection.find(id) == MeanVariance_collection.end()) { libData->Message("noinst"); return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR; }

    try
    {
        mma::TensorRef<double> var1 = mma::detail::getTensor<double>(Args[1]);

        (MeanVariance_collection[id])->compute(var1);
    }
    catch (const mma::LibraryError & libErr)
    {
        libErr.report();
        return libErr.error_code();
    }
    catch (const std::exception & exc)
    {
        mma::detail::handleUnknownException(exc.what(), "MeanVariance::compute()");
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        mma::detail::handleUnknownException(NULL, "MeanVariance::compute()");
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}


extern "C" DLLEXPORT int MeanVariance_mean(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument * Args, MArgument Res)
{
    mma::detail::MOutFlushGuard flushguard;
    const mint id = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    if (MeanVariance_collection.find(id) == MeanVariance_collection.end()) { libData->Message("noinst"); return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR; }

    try
    {
        double res = (MeanVariance_collection[id])->mean();
        MArgument_setReal(Res, res);
    }
    catch (const mma::LibraryError & libErr)
    {
        libErr.report();
        return libErr.error_code();
    }
    catch (const std::exception & exc)
    {
        mma::detail::handleUnknownException(exc.what(), "MeanVariance::mean()");
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        mma::detail::handleUnknownException(NULL, "MeanVariance::mean()");
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}


extern "C" DLLEXPORT int MeanVariance_variance(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument * Args, MArgument Res)
{
    mma::detail::MOutFlushGuard flushguard;
    const mint id = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    if (MeanVariance_collection.find(id) == MeanVariance_collection.end()) { libData->Message("noinst"); return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR; }

    try
    {
        double res = (MeanVariance_collection[id])->variance();
        MArgument_setReal(Res, res);
    }
    catch (const mma::LibraryError & libErr)
    {
        libErr.report();
        return libErr.error_code();
    }
    catch (const std::exception & exc)
    {
        mma::detail::handleUnknownException(exc.what(), "MeanVariance::variance()");
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        mma::detail::handleUnknownException(NULL, "MeanVariance::variance()");
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: This is an amazing work !

Comment: Any chance of version 9 compatibility?

Comment: @wxffles Managed library expressions, which I use a lot, are only available in version 10. This was the main reason why it had to be v10-only. Unfortunately it's not possible to make it work in v9, it's too dependent no v10-only features.

Comment: @Szabolcs Would it make sense to use this to write an updated version of pythonika for ipython?

Comment: @M.R. No.  IMO such interfaces should use MathLink, not LibraryLink.

Comment: Wow, this is really, really great! Question: In `LFun["compute", {{Real, _, "Constant"}}, "Void"],`, what does `"Constant"` mean?

Comment: @nikie The argument types are specified in the same way as in `LibraryFunctionLoad` (with minor restrictions and extensions).  So it just refers to constant passing, as described [in the LibraryLink tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html#374978585): a packed array will be passed to the function without making a copy of it first, and it is assumed that the function will not modify the array.  It is a way to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: @nikie Please do consider it as an experimental thing though ... I am hoping to learn enough from making this first version of LTemplate that I can make the next version much more useful.  To do that I need to find out how LTemplate holds up in real-world usage.  For [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM), it worked pretty well so far, though there are some things for which I haven't yet found ideal solutions (pass a managed library expression through MathLink-based passing is still hanging in the air and done through a hack in IGraph/M).

Comment: @nikie The next project, if I ever have time for it, would be accessing [ITK](http://www.itk.org/) though LTemplate.  For that I'd need to add `MImage` support. The challenge is to make it really convenient to use with heavily templated C++ code such as ITK. I would like ITK filters to operate on any type of MImage.  I guess you're more interested in this kind of application.  Unfortunately I have next to no experience with image processing, but the other day I had a need for ITK.  (eventually I did find ``Image`ITK` ``).

Comment: Ah, I see now. I've looked in the reference page for `LibraryFunctionLoad`, but memory management options weren't mentioned there. I've used LTemplate to access "libSVM" for machine learning (more options and faster than `Classify`), and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much for this.

Comment: @nikie I'm glad to hear it!  Also, it's good that you let me know that you are using it, now I will be more careful about breaking things ;-)  The `"Constant"` thing is documented in the tutorial, see my link above. I tried to link to the correct location within the page but it didn't work, so you'll have to scroll down and find it ..

Comment: time to self-Accept perhaps? :^)

Comment: Hi, @Szabolcs, thank you so much for your package. I am planning to use it to speed up some parts of my code. I encountered a problem. Following LTemplateTutorial.nb, when I run `CompileTemplate[template]`, I got "CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status". Though `.cpp` file is generated, but `LoadTemplate[template]` complains that "LibraryFunction::notfound: Symbol DemoLib not found." What is wrong?

Comment: @Szabolcs I am using mingw. This is my setting `$CCompiler = {
   "Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler,
   "CompilerInstallation" -> 
    "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-7.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\",
   "CompilerName" -> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe"};`

Comment: @matheorem This problem is unrelated to the package. It is about setting up LibraryLink in general. I do not use MinGW with Mathematica. I am sure it can be set up, but it is not officially supported, and there are concerns about compatibility with the MathLink libraries. If there is a problem, it may only manifest itself occasionally. Unless you have a really good reason not to, I recommend you just use the Microsoft compiler. [This works](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools), no GUI tools needed.

Comment: @matheorem To see the exact errors, you can use the same options as in `CreateLibrary`, i.e. `"ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print`

Comment: @matheorem For potential issues, see the link in my first comment here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55037/12  As for what is going on wrong on your machine: it seems to be a linking error (but you need to check the full error message based on my previous comment).  My naive guess about such errors is that it is either because some libraries were not found (i.e. you need to set the path to them somehow), or because they are not compatible (the link I mentioned earlier).  As I said, personally I chose not to bother with MinGW, but I would like to see how to get it working ...

Comment: Hi, @Szabolcs. Thank you so much for patient reply. My mingw-w64 is working fine in other cases, and my own librarylink function which uses `Eigen`. I turn on `ShellOutputFunction` and it points the source of error, here is full output https://pastebin.com/c9bGXmnT .  In short, it complains about `undefined reference to `MLPutFunction'` and other ML* functions. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @matheorem I might not be able to help at all, but let's try.  Please give me the ShellCommandFunction too [and let us continue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58744/matheorem-szabolcs).

Comment: @Szabolcs This is the most useful external package that I have ever used. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just from browsing through the documentation I can only concur with Henrik; this is a very finely crafted work; production-grade software, no less. Thank you!

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I just released a bugfix release. If you use it, please upgrade. There was a problem with iterating through elements of "very" sparse arrays.  If you find any problems, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've taken heed of your advice to first use the tutorials in wolfram groups, so I'll keep this in mind before starting to really use your package.

Comment: Perhaps you can suggest what's wrong here? I'm stumbling on the first example of your tutorial, `CompileTemplate[template,
 "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print
 ]` gives me this [output](https://pastebin.com/8qwjbPha).

Comment: @LLlAMnYP AFAIK Mathematica does not support MinGW out of the box. I assume you configured it yourself (i.e. you set up a compiler for Mathematica yourself instead of letting it detect it).  The configuration seems to be incomplete.  It should link against the MathLink libraries (possible something like `-lMLi4`, but I'm not sure).  I also seem to remember that it was necessary to convert these libraries before they  would work with gcc.  If you don't have a good reason to use gcc, you'll save a lot of trouble by sticking to MSVC.

Comment: @Szabolcs MMA doesn't detect MSVC for me. I have to manually specify `$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler, 
 "CompilerInstallation" -> "D:\\Larkin\\Dev-C++\\MinGW64", 
 "CompilerName" -> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe", 
 "CompileOptions" -> "-O2"}` for compilation to C to work (but not in this case, clearly). Do I actually need the full install of Visual Studio or are the redistributables enough?

Comment: In fact, on my other machine I have VS2017 installed, but MMA 10.2 doesn't autodetect a compiler, and, in fact, ``CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler`` is not among the output of `CCompilers[Full]`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I believe Mma 10.2 should work with MSVC 2015, [after doing this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41691/12). I *won't* work with 2017, only with 2015 and earlier. I use [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) when I'm on Windows, i.e. only command line tools, not the full VS.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Otherwise you can try adding `-lML64i3` (not i4 for M10.2) to the linking options in the compiler setup.   You may also need to [convert libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793370/how-can-i-convert-a-vsts-lib-to-a-mingw-a) to the appropriate format ... I am guessing here because I don't have a Windows computer handy and I have not used gcc with Mathematica for a long time because of these difficulties.

Comment: I mean "It won't work" not "I won't work".

Comment: Ok, I see which direction to move in. Thanks.

Comment: I like this program.