# How to import and export msgpack?

Tags: export, import, format

[MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/index.html) is an efficient binary serialization format, I find it much better than JSON. There is currently (as of v10.3) no support for this in Mathematica.

*Does anyone know of third party packages or other related tools for reading and writing .msgpacks?*

Comment: There are implementations in many languages. I suppose that you could use the ones in c/c++, c# or R, to import msgpack files through the use of LibraryLink, NETLink, or RLink, respectively.

Comment: Yes I usually use Python with msgpack, and I find LibraryLink too convoluted to use, don't you?

Comment: Szabolcs has [done a lot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96127/how-to-simplify-writing-librarylink-code) to simplify the use of LibraryLink.

Comment: That's one way to do, but given the simplicity of the format, I think it is completely realistic to implement it in terms of `BinaryWrite`.  If you don't like LibraryLink, try `BinaryWrite`/`BinaryRead`. These functions are fast, simple to use, and usually work very well for binary formats that indicate the number of following bytes in advance, and thus require no fancy parsing.  msgpack seems to be like that.

Comment: Is this format commonly used for scientific data?  It is well supported (for this purpose) in other comparable systems (Python, MATLAB, Julia, etc.)?  How does it compare to other things that look similar on the surface (like Cap'n Proto)?  Have you used others?

Comment: Also, something else: can you provide benchmark files to test msgpack reading/writing? (Not for speed but for correctness.)

Comment: Final question: glancing at the specification, it appears that arrays are not homogeneous.  This is good for flexibility, but it's going to make it perform not so well.  Every element of an array will need to be read/written one-by-one instead of dumping a *packed array* in one go.  Seeing this, I'm a bit confused about the use of the format: if JSON is too verbose/slow for certain scientific data, why don't we go straight to HDF5 for performance?  Do we really need something in the middle?