# How to simplify writing MathLink code?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, c++

This [wonderful question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96127/how-to-simplify-writing-librarylink-code) inspired me to ask the analogue for MathLink, which is now known as Wolfram Symbolic Transfer Protocol (WSTP).

The basic example addTwo is over complicated and under useful.