# How to carry out arithmetic operations on mcomplex in LibraryFunction

Tags: librarylink

I want to perform some arithmetic inside the C++ code using `mcomplex` data type defined in `WolframLibrary.h`, but the compiler complains that `mcomplex` is an invalid binary operand for `*` and `+`.   **Question:** What do I need to do to carry out arithmetic on `mcomplex` variables?

---

Below is the `.cc` file defining the `LibraryFunciton` called `myFunc`.

```cpp
//mma.cc
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

//Standard LibraryLink functions
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){
    return WolframLibraryVersion;}

DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData){
    return 0;}

//User function called through LibraryFunctionLoad
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int myFunc(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, 
   MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){

    mcomplex I0 = MArgument_getComplex(Args[0]);
    mcomplex I1 = MArgument_getComplex(Args[1]);

    mcomplex result = (I0 + I1)*(I0 + 2*I1) // <--- this is illegal.  HELP!!!

    MArgument_setComplex(Res,result);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `mcomplex` in `WolframLibrary.h` you can see that it is simply a struct with two real numbers:

```
typedef struct {mreal ri[2];} mcomplex;
```

There are no `+` or `*` been overloaded by `mcomplex`. So in order for them to work, we need to define them ourselves:

```
//mma.cc
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){
    return WolframLibraryVersion;}

DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData){
    return 0;}

mcomplex operator*(mcomplex m1, mcomplex m2){
    mcomplex m3 = {m1.ri[0]*m2.ri[0] - m1.ri[1]*m2.ri[1],
        m1.ri[0]*m2.ri[1]+m1.ri[1]*m2.ri[0]};
    return m3;
}
mcomplex operator*(mreal r1, mcomplex m2){
    mcomplex m3 = {r1*m2.ri[0], r1*m2.ri[1]};
    return m3;
}
mcomplex operator+(mcomplex m1, mcomplex m2){
    mcomplex m3 = {m1.ri[0]+m2.ri[0], m1.ri[1]+m2.ri[1]};
    return m3;
}

//User function called through LibraryFunctionLoad
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int myFunc(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, 
   MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){

    mcomplex I0 = MArgument_getComplex(Args[0]);
    mcomplex I1 = MArgument_getComplex(Args[1]);

    mcomplex result = (I0 + I1)*(I0 + 2*I1);

    MArgument_setComplex(Res,result);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Just cast to a C++ `std::complex<double>`, and compute with it as usual.

---

`mcomplex` is defined as

```
typedef struct {mreal ri[2];} mcomplex;
```

where `mreal` is just a `double`.  This means that `mcomplex` is always two `double`s, following each other in memory with no gap.

[Since C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), `std::complex<double>` is guaranteed to have the same layout, which means that it is safe to `reinterpret_cast` to it.

[`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) has the usual arithmetic (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) as well as many other functions already implemented for it in the C++ standard library, which makes it very easy to work with.

Here's an example:

```cpp
/* cpl.cpp */

#include <WolframLibrary.h>
#include <complex>

/* Return the version of Library Link */
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

/* Initialize Library */
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

/* Uninitialize Library */
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
}

/* Conversions between std::complex<double> and `mcomplex` */

inline const std::complex<double> &from_mcomplex(const mcomplex &z) { return reinterpret_cast<const std::complex<double> &>(z); }
inline std::complex<double> &from_mcomplex(mcomplex &z) { return reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double> &>(z); }

inline const mcomplex &to_mcomplex(const std::complex<double> &z) { return reinterpret_cast<const mcomplex &>(z); }
inline mcomplex &to_mcomplex(std::complex<double> &z) { return reinterpret_cast<mcomplex &>(z); }

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int mult(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    mcomplex a = MArgument_getComplex(Args[0]);
    mcomplex b = MArgument_getComplex(Args[1]);
    MArgument_setComplex(Res, to_mcomplex( from_mcomplex(a) * from_mcomplex(b) ));
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

```
lib = CreateLibrary[{"cpl.cpp"}, "cpl"];
mult = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "mult", {Complex, Complex}, Complex];

mult[I, I]
(* -1. + 0. I *)
```

---

[LTemplate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96127/12) already has this particular conversion built in.  Its `mma::complex_t` type is just an alias for `std::complex<double>`.

Example:

```cpp
// Cpl.h
struct Cpl {
  mma::complex_t mult(mma::complex_t a, mma::complex_t b) {
    return a*b;
  }
};
```

```
template = LClass["Cpl",
   {LFun["mult", {Complex, Complex}, Complex]}
  ];

CompileTemplate[template]

LoadTemplate[template]

obj = Make[Cpl]
(* Cpl[1] *)

obj@"mult"[I, I]
(* -1. + 0. I *)
```