# connecting to an existing application's C API from Mathematica

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, api

I have a general question about accessing the contents of an existing application's C API (https://libfive.com/) from Mathematica.

Can it be done, and some hints on how?

I am about to embark on reading the hefty "WSTP and External Program Communication" guidelines on the Mathematica web site but I was wondering if there was anybody that could direct or give hints on the correct steps atleast to take initially.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be to write a `LibraryLink` package to interface with libfive's C++ API.  If you use the [LTemplate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96128/9490) package to help, you could have this up and running in very short order.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into LibraryLink and the LTemplate package.

Comment: Did you create in interface to libfive?