# Why I can't install this package

Tags: packages, librarylink

I am trying to run C++ in Mathematica. I got a package "LTemplate" from the answer from Szabolcs in this post: [How to simplify writing LibraryLink code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96127/how-to-simplify-writing-librarylink-code). However I can't install it.

This is what I did:

1. I put the package in "C:\Temp\LTemplate-master".
2. I set the directory by "SetDirectory["C:\Temp\LTemplate-master\LTemplate"]"
3. When I ran the command `` Needs["LTemplate`"] `` or `` << LTemplate` `` , I got the following error messages:

> Get::noopen: Cannot open `` LTemplate`LTemplateInner` `` .

\$ContextPath::cxlist: Cannot set \$ContextPath to {LClassContext[], LTemplate`,SymbolicC`,CCompilerDriver`,DocumentationSearch`,ResourceLocator`,URLUtilities`,HighlightingCompatibility`,PacletManager`,System`,Global`}; value must be a list of strings ending in `.

Can some one tell me how to install the package?

Comment: Have you seen the *Installation* and the *Getting Started*  instructions at [LTemplate github repo](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate) ?

Comment: As with all classical _Mathematica_ packages, you are suppose to put the contents of the package into `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications","LTemplate"}]`.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks.