# MathLink and C++ vector container

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability, c++

## The Problem.

I have a C++ class that does some computations, and returns a C++ vector object (the length of which can possibly vary with each run).

I want to store each of these vectors as a list in *Mathematica*, so, for instance, if three iterations returns the vectors `(0, 1)`, `(0.02, 0.9)` and `(0.04, 0.73)`, I want this output to be written into a *Mathematica* list of the form `{{0,1},{0.02, 0.9},{0.04, 0.73}}`.

## My limitations.

This is the first time I am trying to mess with MathLink. Having spent all of today trying to get this to work, I'm feeling pretty lost. The documentation that has shipped with my *Mathematica* distribution, is helpful only in that I know what to do to write most of the template file. But I can't quite understand how to finish it, and what to do next.

## Operating System and other information

I am on a Mac running Snow Leopard 10.6.8. *Mathematica* is installed in the usual place: `/Applications/Mathematica.app`

## Code

First, what I believe are the relevant portions of the C++ code that I already have

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<deque>
#include<cmath>
// and a bunch of other files

class mp{


// stuff that defines the class
public:

// some functions
vector <long double> viewCurrent(); // returns the (t, x) vector for the current state of the
                                    // system; note that x can be a vector itself
 
};
```

What I would like is to store the output of `mp::viewCurrent()` into *Mathematica* lists. How do I do this?

Comment: Your life will greatly be simplified if you are willing to use `double` instead of `long double`.

Comment: It seems that what you are asking for is an example of how to access from Mathematica a function that returns variable length vectors.  [Here's an example for LibraryLink](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8442/12).

Comment: Thanks for linking to LibraryLink. Let's see if I can get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then let me give you a minimal example using `LibraryLink`. Create a file named `my_vector.cpp` (it is in my "tmp" folder here).

```c
#include "mathlink.h"
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include <vector>

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){
  return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData)
{
  return 0;
}

DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) 
{
  return;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int vectortest(WolframLibraryData libData, MLINK mlp)
{

  using std::vector;
  long len;
  vector<int> vec;

  MLCheckFunction(mlp, "List", &len);
  if (len != 0) {
    libData->Message("0 arguments expected.");
    return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
  }
  MLNewPacket(mlp);

  for (int iter = 0; iter < 10; ++iter) {
    vec.push_back(iter);
  }

  vector<int>::iterator it;

  MLPutFunction(mlp,"List", vec.size());
  for (it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); ++it) {
    MLPutInteger(mlp, *it);
  }  
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Now open a Mathematica and compile it. This assumes, that you have a running c-compiler which is recognized by Mathematica

```
<< CCompilerDriver`
CreateLibrary[{"tmp/my_vector.cpp"}, "my_vector", 
 "ShellOutputFunction" :> Print, "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print]
```

The options are not necessary, but it helps when you see the compilation messages and the command-line. Mathematica places the ready to use dll|so|dylib in a folder in the search-path. Now, you can load it directly:

```
vecf = LibraryFunctionLoad["my_vector", "vectortest", LinkObject, LinkObject];
vecf[]

(*
  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
*)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and is so much more illustrative than the documentation out there! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting here because the comments field is too small to contain this. This really should be in the comments, though.

I think I have a solution that works for the particular question I asked. However, I haven't yet gotten LibraryLink to work. This is a MathLink based solution.

I am posting the appropriate snippets of code here.

## The template file

I will call my template file `template.tm`

```
:Begin:
:Function:      WrapperAroundClass
:Pattern:       Wrapper[Input1_Integer, Input2_Real, Input3_?NumberQ]
:Arguments:     {Input1, Input2, Input3}
:ArgumentTypes: {Manual}
:ReturnType:    Manual
:End:
```

I am only passing back lists from my c++ code to *Mathematica*. I am not sure how passing lists as inputs will work, though it might work the same way.

## The c++ file

I will call my c++ file `WrapperAroundClass.cpp`

```cpp
// include all the files needed here
#include "mp.h" // include the class I want to work with
#include "mathlink.h"

void WrapperAroundClass(){ // contains actual code

// fetch inputs from Mathematica
int Input1;
MLGetInteger(stdlink, &Input1); // fetch the others similarly
...
// finish fetching data

// do things with it

// now pass the data back
// class has a function mp::view_current() that returns a vector

vector<double> storage;

MLPutFunction(stdlink, "List", storage.size()); // tell mathematica a list of some size is 
                                                //coming
int j = 0;
while(j < storage.size()){ 
    MLPutDouble(stdlink, storage.at(j)); // pass the list element by element
    j++;
}
}

// write the default main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    return MLMain(argc, argv);
}
```

In the example that I have posted here, storage has depth 1. Multiple depths can be handled in the obvious way; I am not sure if this is a terribly slow way of doing things.

To finish, now `mprep` the template file to get `template.o`, and compile `WrapperAroundClass.cpp` to get `WrapperAroundClass.o`. Finally use the C++ compiler to link them to create the executable.

Feed this to *Mathematica* using `link = Import[myPath<>"WrapperAroundClass.out"]` where `myPath` is a string that contains the path to where the executable resides. You will now have a function called `Wrapper` defined inside *Mathematica*.

## Disclaimer

This is a brute force solution, and I am in no way pretending that this is elegant. I kind of like it though, because with minimal code changes it lets me pipe output to *Mathematica*.