# How to match random number generator to R?

Tags: random, rlink

Although I know the algorithm that R is using for pseudo-random numbers I am unable to match the generation of random numbers.

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.3"]
REvaluate["RNGkind()"]
```

> ```
> {"Mersenne-Twister", "Inversion"}
> ```

From the R documentation for [Random Number Generation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/Random) this means that the Mersenne-Twister algorithm is used for pseudo-random numbers and the inversion method is used to create random normals.

Taking a sample of from the standard normal in R.

```
REvaluate["set.seed(115)"]
rRNorm = REvaluate["rnorm(5)"]
```

> ```
> {0.632375, 0.572379, 0.540476, -0.184169, 0.11106}
> ```

I expect that I should be able to match this pseudo-random set in Wolfram Language by using the same algorithm and method.

```
SeedRandom[115, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]
InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 5]]
```

> ```
> {-0.77278, 1.25667, -0.584935, 1.39649, 0.191121}
> ```

However the set does not match.

I have also tried.

```
SeedRandom[115, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 5]
```

> ```
> {1.37915, -1.06197, 1.39337, -0.780701, 0.809144}
> ```

With equally unsatisfactory comparison.

How do I match the pseudo-random number generation between R and Wolfram Language?  Of course, without having to call R.

Comment: While I may be wrong, I thought that pseudorandom number generators will just create random bits. There are multiple ways to make a random integer or a random floating point number from those.  There are lots of steps to get from those random bits to normally distributed real numbers. I think there are also multiple variations of the Mersenne twister (or multiple parameters that can be used).

Comment: It might not be of much help, but may be worth a look anyway https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19541/12

Comment: "How to match random number generator to R?" -- Do not. (That was easy.)

Comment: Very likely the seeds get used to initialize in different ways even though the RNGs are the same.

Comment: @AntonAntonov If only it was that easy. :-)  Unfortunately I want to run a complementary process in Wolfram Language to one that is in R and I need to match random number generation to do so.

Comment: @Edmund What's wrong with calling R? (seriously.)

Comment: If the answer is not trivial, it would be likely to involve a lot of reverse engineering to see how they works. (unless they're completely documented)