# Executing C programs within mathematica

Tags: java, python, c++

I have a requirement for executing a C program within Mathematica. The user will provide the inputs and the expected results on a front end. Mathematica runs the C file, obtains the result for the provided inputs and compares with the user provided expected results. Further, a green pass button will be displayed if the results matched else a red failed button will be displayed. Later, I want to be able to do the same for C++, Python, Java, and Perl programs. Anyone has worked on this before ?

Warm regards,
Anuk

Comment: [MathLink](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/mathlink/) is your friend.

Comment: You can use .NET to load DLL in Mathematica
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromMathematica.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an executable from within Mathematica, and read in the results, you can use the following syntax:

```
Import["!executablename", "someformat"]
```

The "!" indicates that the program will be run and the output read.  Choose the appropriate format in `Import`.  You can also use "!" with other input functions, such as `ReadList`.

For tighter integration with C, the answers here are exhaustive:

- [Minimal effort method for integrating C++ functions into Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/minimal-effort-method-for-integrating-c-functions-into-mathematica)