# How to use C language functions in Mathematica?

Tags: librarylink

I'm trying to find out the way to use c-functions in Mathematica (I'm using 14 version) on OS X 10.10.

For example I've got this lines of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double helloWorld(double a) {
    return 2 * a;
}
```

Then I've tried to make a shared library like this:

```
gcc -dynamiclib -o mylib.dylib hello.c
```

After that I'm trying to load this function in mathematica:

```
LibraryFunctionLoad["~/term/mylib.dylib", "helloWorld", {Real}, Real];
```

But mathematica tells me that it cannot load my function

```
LibraryFunction::libload: The function helloWorld was not loaded from the file ~/term/mylib.dylib. >>
```

Is anyone has clue how to make this things work?

Comment: Is your function helloWorld visible in your library?  I don't see anything to export (make public) that symbol.  I've done this before, on windows where you have to explicitly declare which functions in a dll are to be visible.  If you don't they aren't.  It may be different in OS X of course.

Comment: I guess they are visible
$ nm -a libksr.dylib

0000000000000f70 T _helloWorld U dyld_stub_binder

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8438/12 `LibraryFunctionLoad` is meant to be used only with functions specifically written for LibraryLink.  If you are going to use LibraryLink, you will need to create a LibraryLink-compatible wrapper for whatever you need to call. There are other methods than LibraryLink for calling C functions, all described in the thread I linked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can look here for more examples and details:

- http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/189092
- http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/189735

In short, do the following (call the file DoubleIt.c):

```
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

 DLLEXPORT int DoubleIt(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
         mint x;
         mint result;
         x = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
         result = 2*x;
         MArgument_setInteger(Res,result);
        return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Then, in Mathematica, do the following (you will need a compiler on your machine):

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];

lib = CreateLibrary[{"DoubleIt.c"},"DoubleIt"];
DoubleIt = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"DoubleIt",{Integer},Integer];
```

Then you can use it as a function:

```
DoubleIt[4]
```

That should return the integer 8. You can also do this with real numbers, but you will need to change the various *Integer* functions to use *Real*. So:

```
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

DLLEXPORT int DoubleIt2(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
     mreal x;
     mreal result;
     x = MArgument_getReal(Args[0]);
     result = 2*x;
     MArgument_setReal(Res,result);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
```

}

And:

```
lib = CreateLibrary[{"c:\\users\\arnoudb.wri\\DoubleIt2.c"}, "DoubleIt2"];
DoubleIt2 = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "DoubleIt2", {Real}, Real];
```

And then:

```
DoubleIt2[4.2]
```

(Which gives 8.4)