# Open LabView's TDMS file?

Tags: import, hardware

How to open the National Instruments LabView [TDMS](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3727/en/) files?

Has anyone developed a library or code for easily importing these? National Instruments provide a [DLL and specification for the format](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3727/en/). There is also a [python library](https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS) for opening TDMS. Maybe you have some tips for easily developing an import module?

Comment: It's likely less trouble to convert it to something that Mathematica can read using external tools.

Comment: If you're willing to put in the time to make a package that uses the DLL, [check here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8443/12).

Comment: @Szabolcs, I am using Mac OS. It would be nice to have a OS independent approach.

Comment: Anyone who's up for this will want to read [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) and [this](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/5696/en/).