# Initialization Cells in CDF

Tags: dynamic, notebooks, cdf-format, initialization

I am wanting to run about 15 pages of initialization cells in a CDF, but can't seem to do so. I have set the InitializationCellEvaluation to True and InitializationCellWarning to False, but it doesn't work in the CDF. (works just fine in the .nb) I saw something about the NotebookDynamicExpression, but I wasn't sure how to run a ton of code through it.

Are there any alternatives? I use no Manipulate or Dynamic functions in my code either.
For example...

```
GenerateDisplayShotsFor := 
  Quiet[Button[
    Style["GENERATE", Bold, FontFamily -> "Terminal", 20, 
     Background -> LightBlue], 
    CreateWindow[
     DocumentNotebook[DisplayShotsFor, WindowTitle -> "Shots For", 
      WindowFrame -> "ModelessDialog", 
      Background -> RGBColor[48/240, 164/240, 220/240], 
      Editable -> False, TextAlignment -> Center , 
      WindowFloating -> False, 
      WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}]]]];
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is not going to work.You have to put those definitions inside `Initialization` in `DynamicModule` or use `SaveDefinitions` for `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a good idea to look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/understanding-cdf) more more information about writing CDF-happy notebooks.  In brief, `Initialization` cells won't function properly in the CDF format.  For example if we have the following initialization cell:

```
a = 1;
```

And subsequent cell that is not an initialization cell

```
Manipulate[b + x, {x, 1, 10, 1}]
Manipulate[a + x, {x, 1, 10, 1}, Initialization :> (a = 1;)]
```

The first `Manipulate` will not evaluate `b` when exported in CDF format.  All of your initialization needs to go in the `Initialization` option of `Manipulate` in this case.  As mentioned in the question references above, this seems to be the easiest way to get initialization into a CDF, even if Manipulate is not being used.

Comment: Thank you, but my initialization cells are buttons, graphs, images, and functions being defined that wait for user inputted values. Does Manipulate still work on them? I haven't figured how to wrap them.

Comment: @user8736 You might be asking a bit much out of CDFs.  [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13844/7167) has some insight into managing code for CDFs.

Comment: Okay. I understand. Thank you for the link. If you know of another way to deploy a secured (unable to view code etc) notebook feel free to say so. Again, thanks for your help.