# Use of Manipulate in CDF documents

Tags: manipulate, cdf-format

I am trying to publish a cdf document, but I'm having some problems with the function `Manipulate` with this code:

```
Manipulate[x + 1, {x}]
```

In *Mathematica*, when I set `x = d + d^3` in the input field, I get this output:

> `Manipulate[x + 1, {{x, d + d^3}}]`

This is what I want. However, it seems that the cdf player is only able to evaluate the expression `x + 1` when `x` is a number and not a more complicated expression. Is this true or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  FreeCDF only supports numbers in input fields, see here: http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/details-for-mathematica-programmers.html

Comment: I suspected that, thank you anyway.

Comment: I think this restriction is there to prevent people from making a CDF that could evaluate arbitrary Mathematica code. (And thus using the CDF player as a free Mathematica)

Comment: Currently, the only way around these limitations of the FreeCDF player are either to get PlayerPro (which is a per license cost) or an Enterprise version of *Mathematica* in which you can "super-sign" CDFs to achieve more functionality.

Comment: I'll copy @kale's comment as an answer since I could not find an answer that gets straight to the point.  [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3964/7167), however, has extensive discussion about CDFs

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the behavior you are observing is expected.

> Currently, the only way around these limitations of the FreeCDF player are either to get PlayerPro (which is a per license cost) or an Enterprise version of Mathematica in which you can "super-sign" CDFs to achieve more functionality.