# Works in mathematica but not as cdf preview or web embedded cdf

Tags: cdf-format, simulation

I have a curvature simulation with the help of m_goldberg that works in mathematica but does not work as a cdf in cdf preview.
In mathematica it says nothing while in cdf preview or while web embedded says:

Radius radius[0,1] should be a pair of numbers or a scaled Offset factor...same with coordinate r[0,1] and center[0,1].I've been changing the code for a while with no good results.Please Help Thanks

```
Clear[t]; forms = {{3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}};
lbls = ToString /@ forms;
indxs = Range[Length[forms]];
rules = Thread[Rule[indxs, lbls]];
(r[t_, #] = forms[[#]]) & /@ indxs;
(dr[t_, #] = D[r[t, #], t]) & /@ indxs;
(d2r[t_, #] = D[r[t, #], {t, 2}]) & /@ indxs;
(uT[t_, #] = 
     Simplify[dr[t, #]/Norm[dr[t, #]], t \[Element] Reals]) & /@ indxs;
(vN[t_, #] = 
     Simplify[With[{du = D[uT[t, #], t]}, du/Norm[du]], 
      t \[Element] Reals]) & /@ indxs;
(radius[t_, #] = 
     Simplify[
      Norm[dr[t, #]]^3/
       Abs[dr[t, #][[1]] d2r[t, #][[2]] - 
         dr[t, #][[2]] d2r[t, #][[1]]], t \[Element] Reals]) & /@ 
  indxs;
(center[t_, #] = 
     Simplify[r[t, #] + radius[t, #] vN[t, #], 
      t \[Element] Reals]) & /@ indxs;
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{RGBColor[0.6, 0.6, 0.8], 
    Disk[center[t, k], radius[t, k]]}], 
  ParametricPlot[r[t, k], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Point[r[t, k]]}]], {{k, 1, "function"}, 
  rules, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: For starters, add `SaveDefinitions->True` as option to `Manipulate`. The problem is that you define your stuff in the global context which is not available inside the Manipulate after you have restarted the Kernel (or open your CDF in the player).

Comment: As per above comment you need to localize these variables and/or investigate `Initialization` option to `Manipulate`

Comment: Unless the simple mistake imo it can be marked asa duplicate of [understanding CDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4256/5478)

Comment: I overlooked the easiest part. SaveDefinitions totally works.Thanks so much!!!!