# How to load data into a Manipulate expression

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, data

I have data showing truncated octahedron geometry changing with time. How can I read those data into a `Manipulate` expression? To be specific, I want to manipulate time and have other parameters change correspondingly as in my data. Those parameter value should show simultaneously.

Now I have geometry that I can change by varying the parameters. My `Manipulate` code is

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{RegionPlot3D[
     x + y + z < 0.866 A && x + y - z < 0.866 A && 
      x - y + z < 0.866 A && -x + y + z < 0.866 A && 
      x + y + z > -0.866 A && x + y - z > -0.866 A && 
      x - y + z > -0.866 A && -x + y + z > -0.866 A, {x, -0.5*r*A, 
      0.5*r*A}, {y, -0.5*r*A, 0.5*r*A}, {z, -0.5*r*A, 0.5*r*A}, 
     ImageSize -> 300, Mesh -> 1, PlotRange -> {-16, 16}], 
    SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, {"volume(nm^3)", 
    ScientificForm[
     NIntegrate[
      Boole[void = 
        x + y + z < 0.866 A && x + y - z < 0.866 A && 
         x - y + z < 0.866 A && -x + y + z < 0.866 A && 
         x + y + z > -0.866 A && x + y - z > -0.866 A && 
         x - y + z > -0.866 A && -x + y + z > -0.866 A], {x, -0.5*r*A,
        0.5*r*A}, {y, -0.5*r*A, 0.5*r*A}, {z, -0.5*r*A, 0.5*r*A}], 
     3] }, {"{002}Facets area(nm^2)", 
    ScientificForm[12*(0.866 A - 0.5*r*A)^2, 
     3]}, {"{111}Facets area(nm^2)", 
    ScientificForm[
     4*(3)^(0.5)*((0.866 A)^2 - 3*(0.866 A - 0.5*r*A)^2), 3]}}], 
  {{A, 20, "Distance between {111} facets (nm)"}, 1, 20, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{r, 1.4, "Aspect ratio"}, 1.04, 1.4, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

And a small subset of my data is

```
Time  A      r 
200   16.09  1.084524549
210   15.74  1.062261753
220   15.02  1.053262317
225   14.59  1.067169294
235   14.21  1.073187896
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[{o, g, r, q, l, A, lim, x, y, z},
 o = Cos[Pi/6]; g = 0.5; 
 l = {{200, 16.09, 1.084524549}, {210, 15.74, 1.062261753}, {220, 15.02, 1.053262317}, 
      {225, 14.59, 1.067169294}, {235, 14.21, 1.073187896}};
 q = x + y + z < o A && x + y - z < o A  && 
     x - y + z < o A && -x + y + z < o A && x + y + z > -o A && 
    x + y - z > -o A && x - y + z > -o A && -x + y + z > -o A;
 lim = {{x, -g r A, g r A}, {y, -g r A, g r A}, {z, -g r A, g r A}};
 Manipulate[(
  {A, r} = Select[l, #[[1]] == t &][[1, 2 ;; 3]];
   Grid[{{RegionPlot3D[q, Evaluate[Sequence @@ lim], Mesh -> 1, PlotRange -> 16 {-1, 1}]}, 
         {"volume(nm^3)", NIntegrate[Evaluate@Boole[q], Evaluate[Sequence @@ lim]]}, 
         {"{002}Facets area(nm^2)", 12 (o A - g r A)^2}, 
         {"{111}Facets area(nm^2)", 4 3^g ((o A)^2 - 3 (o A - g r A)^2)}}]), 
   {t, l[[All, 1]],  ControlType -> Slider}, SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wonderful, You excellent coding makes the structure much clearer! But is it possible to make the time as slide bar with dispersed value? As it makes people much easier to play the evolution with the changing time.

Comment: The slide bar that you can only slide to the value that is recorded in the data. For instance, 200, 210, 220... but not any value between.

Comment: Fantastic! Such amazing, I feel so much to learn in the mathematica! If possible, we would like to acknowledge your help once our research is published. Could you please leave any contact? You can always reach me by zezhong.zhang@monash.edu

Comment: And there is a small bug with Evaluate function, that the image and volume used the evaluate does not change with parameters or time.

Comment: @JackZhang Please refer to: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1580/10261. My contact address is in my profile.

Comment: @JackZhang Bug corrected

Comment: one small complaint: using `l` as variable is not good idea as it appears as `1` depending on font and screen mode which can be confusing. May be better to use another letter instead of `l`

Comment: @Nasser My eyesight is too good for making that si11y mistake

Comment: Bit of wondering, why it works perfectly in the .nb but has errors when exported to cdf?

Comment: @JackZhang Are you aware of all of this things: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3964/193 ?

Comment: @belisarius Is the format cause the problem? I don't quite understand here. I used both CDF and CDF pro to view it but none of them works. The cdf pro says for one of the error:            Select::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Select[l$91700,#1[[1]]==FE`t$$85&]. >>

Comment: @belisarius I looked the help document explaining the error message. But not sure why it went all right in .nb not in cdf. Could you suggest a way to solve it for cdf manipulation?

Comment: @JackZhang Check it now

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for editing, this one can be viewed in CDF! But quite strange, the shape and volume dynamics can only happens in .nb but not in cdf.

Comment: @belisarius I changed the function from DynamicModule to Dynamics, the unchanged image and volume value problem is solved. Is the Evaluate[sequence @@ lim] not cooperate with DynamicModule when converting into cdf? In general the problem fixed, thanks a lot for you kind helps. Cheers, Jack.