# Manipulators and Dynamic in more concise code

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

Is there a way to update dynamic variables through a function. I was looking back at one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6801880/788553) from Heike where she showed me how to make my custom `Manipulate`. What I'm finding very annoying is having to copy and paste code for every variable I have to update. Consider this:

```
Panel[
    DynamicModule[
        {
        a = 1, b = 100,
        c = a + b + 1, d = a - b + 1
        }, 
        Column[{
            Grid[{
                {
                MyControl[Manipulator[Dynamic[a, (a = #; c = a + b + 1; d = a - b + 1) &], {0, 1}],"a", Dynamic[PaddedForm[a, 5]]],
                MyControl[Manipulator[Dynamic[b, (b = #; c = a + b + 1; d = a - b + 1) &], {100, 200}], "b", Dynamic[PaddedForm[b, 5]]],
                }
                }, Alignment -> Left],
            {Dynamic@c, Dynamic@d}
        }],
        Initialization :> (
            MyControl[manip_, left_String, right_] := Row[{Style[left, "TI", 14], manip, right}, Spacer[1]];
        )
    ], 
    ImageSize -> {600, 100}
]
```

This allows me to change `a` and `b` and every time I change them `c` and `d` get updated and they are displayed:

[image: screenshot]

Question, is there any way to remove the redundancy of the code? I would love to have a function which updates all the variables, in this case, `c` and `d`. For instance I want something like this:

```
Panel[
    DynamicModule[
        {
        a = 1, b = 100,
        c = a + b + 1, d = a - b + 1
        }, 
        Column[{
            Grid[{
                {
                MyControl[Manipulator[Dynamic[a, (a = #; updateVars[]) &], {0, 1}],"a", Dynamic[PaddedForm[a, 5]]],
                MyControl[Manipulator[Dynamic[b, (b = #; updateVars[]) &], {100, 200}], "b", Dynamic[PaddedForm[b, 5]]],
                }
                }, Alignment -> Left],
            {Dynamic@c, Dynamic@d}
        }],
        Initialization :> (
            MyControl[manip_, left_String, right_] := Row[{Style[left, "TI", 14], manip, right}, Spacer[1]];
            updateVars[] := (c = a + b + 1; d = a - b + 1);
        )
    ], 
    ImageSize -> {600, 100}
]
```

That way, if later on I introduce something else that needs to be updated every time I move a single sliders then I can just add it to `updateVars`. Unfortunately, the above does not work. Anyone knows how to make it work?

Comment: Your code works OK in my machine, with a minor quirk solved by declaring _MyControl_ in the DynamicModule vars section, and adding a _Dynamic@_ before each MyControl[] invocation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is the following set of golden rules:

- Use internal (local to the enclosing `DynamicModule`) `update` functions in the `Dynamic` controls to update common variables depending on other dynamic variables.
- Define the update function(s) in the **body** of the `DynamicModule` (instead of using `Initialization :> (...)` as `Initialization` is only evaluated when the body is first displayed on screen, which might be too late, see details of [evaluation sequence here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153/89)).
- Initialize dependent variables by calling the `update` function early, earlier than the actual output is displayed first (which is the `Column[...]` object). Without this, you will only see unevaluated front-end variables until you first move any of the sliders, which in turn would trigger an `update` call, assigning all dependent front-end variables their appropriate numerical values.

Like this:

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{a = 1, b = 100, c, d, update, MyControl},
  MyControl[manip_, left_, right_] := Row[{Style[left, "TI", 14], manip, right}, Spacer@1];
  update[] := (
    c = a + b + 1;
    d = a - b + 1;
    );
  update[]; (* actual initialization *)
  Column[{Grid[{
      {MyControl[Manipulator[Dynamic[a, (a = #; update[]) &], {0, 1}],
         "a", Dynamic[PaddedForm[a, 5]]],
       MyControl[
        Manipulator[Dynamic[b, (b = #; update[]) &], {100, 200}], "b",
         Dynamic[PaddedForm[b, 5]]]}
      }, Alignment -> Left],
    {Dynamic@c, Dynamic@d}
    }]], ImageSize -> {600, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the set of rules. Just one question, why does `MyControl` not included as local as you did with `update`?

Comment: Oh, good point, I simply forgot. It's there now. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: I have one problem. I just made a nice GUI using the rules you specified (love them by the way) but now when I made a CDF all the dynamic content is grayed out. Could this be due to the lack of initialization?

Comment: @jmlopez: Yes, functions with `DownValues` might cause security issues in deployed CDF's. Please see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75/89) answer for a workaround, and [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3964/89) (especially the parts about **Securiy issues**) to understand a bit better what is happening.

Comment: I don't think this is because of a security issue. I have the version in which I did it the old way and it worked fine. But now instead I get this: http://i.imgur.com/RE31Z.png

Comment: never mind. It is a security issue. Darn! Well, I guess try to see if belisarius modifications work with CDFs.

Answer (score 5):

As I commented above, this is your code running OK in my machine. I commented on the (very) small modifications I did:

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{MyControl (*add*), a = 1, b = 100, c = a + b + 1,  d = a - b + 1}, 
  Column[{Grid[{{Dynamic@ (*add Dynamic*)
        MyControl[
         Manipulator[Dynamic[a, (a = #; updateVars[]) &], {0, 1}], 
         "a", Dynamic[PaddedForm[a, 5]]], 
       Dynamic@MyControl[  (*add Dynamic*)
         Manipulator[Dynamic[b, (b = #; updateVars[]) &], {100, 200}],
          "b", Dynamic[PaddedForm[b, 5]]],}}, 
     Alignment -> Left], {Dynamic@c, Dynamic@d}}], 
  Initialization :> (MyControl[manip_, left_String, right_] := 
     Row[{Style[left, "TI", 14], manip, right}, Spacer[1]];
    updateVars[] := (c = a + b + 1; d = a - b + 1);)], 
 ImageSize -> {600, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why the example I posted still doesn't work (left it overnight), and now I copy and paste the exact same code on another cell and now it works as you mentioned.Even without adding `Dynamic`. In any case, I think I will go with István set of golden rules.