# How to enable-dynamics on CDF's on web?

Tags: cdf-format, version-8

Went through the wizard to export cdf /w embed code:
[image: deployment]

The positions and sizing are correct, but there's no interactive side to it:
[image: bubblechart]

data I'm using:

```
{{"acerbic", 3, 5, 1.3*10^6}, {"acetic", 3, 7, 213000}, {"acetonic", 
  1, 4, 2000}, {"achromatic", 3, 6, 16000}, {"acidic", 3, 6, 
  500}, {"acoustic", 3, 7, 2000}, {"acrobatic", 3, 6, 
  3000}, {"acrostic", 4, 8, Null}, {"acrylic", 3, 5, 
  220000}, {"acyclic", 6, 8, 270000}, {"adiabatic", 6, 7, 
  40000}, {"aerobatic", 3, 6, 2000}, {"aerobic", 7, 4, 
  1.6*10^6}, {"aerodynamic", 7, 7, 160000}, {"aeronautic", 2, 2, 
  5000}, {"aesthetic", 5, 3, 500}, {"agnostic", 3, 5, 
  5000}, {"agoraphobic", 7, 3, 200000}, {"agronomic", 3, 5, 
  5000}, {"alcoholic", 2, 1, 1000}, {"alembic", 2, 1, 
  20000}, {"algebraic", 6, 3, 5000}, {"algorithmic", 5, 2, 
  2500.}, {"aliphatic", 7, 2, 13000}, {"allegoric", 5, 2, 
  1000}, {"allelic", 8, 5, 2400.}, {"allergenic", 8, 5, 
  48000}, {"allergic", 8, 3, 1000}, {"allotropic", 7, 6, 
  3000}, {"almanac", 6, 7, Null}, {"alphabetic", 7, 2, 
  Null}, {"alphanumeric", 6, 7, 1000}, {"altruistic", 4, 7, 
  7000}, {"amnesiac", 5, 6, 4000}, {"amnesic", 6, 5, 
  500}, {"amniotic", 4, 2, 500}, {"amoebic", 2, 1, 1000}, {"anabolic",
   4, 7, Null}, {"anachronistic", 4, 7, 1500.}, {"anaerobic", 3, 5, 
  10000}, {"anagrammatic", 8, 10, Null}, {"analgesic", 3, 7, 
  60000}, {"analytic", 7, 7, 3000}, {"anamorphic", 2, 6, 
  3000}, {"anapestic", 3, 5, 90000}, {"anaphoric", 6, 4, 
  1000000}, {"anarchic", 7, 5, 12000000}, {"anarchistic", 4, 4, 
  50000}, {"anatomic", 2, 2, 30000}, {"androgenic", 2, 4, 
  60000}, {"anechoic", 3, 4, 50000}, {"anemic", 2, 1, 
  200000}, {"anesthetic", 2, 6, 40000}, {"angelic", 3, 6, 
  44000}, {"anharmonic", 4, 7, Null}, {"animistic", 3, 5, 
  100000}, {"anionic", 3, 7, 2.2*10^6}, {"anisotropic", 3, 6, 
  2.8*10^6}, {"anorectic", 6, 1, 60000}, {"anorexic", 5, 6, 
  4000}, {"antagonistic", 1, 5, 550000}, {"antarctic", 3, 4, 
  320000}, {"anthropic", 5, 5, 8000}, {"anthropocentric", 2, 5, 
  10000000}, {"anthropogenic", 1, 5, 12000000}, {"anthropometric", 3, 
  6, 103000}, {"anthropomorphic", "", "", Null}, {"antibiotic", "", 
  "", Null}, {"antic", "", "", Null}, {"anticlimactic", "", "", 
  Null}, {"anticyclonic", "", "", Null}, {"antidemocratic", "", "", 
  Null}}
```

And the code:

```
label = Tooltip[{##2}, 
    Grid[{{"Name", #}, {"Usability ", #2}, {"Relevancy", #3}, \
{"Market Size", #4}}, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]] &;
BubbleChart[label @@@ data, ChartStyle -> 24];
```

[this is the live url](http://juggernautmotorsports.ca/blogs/z/x/test.html)

Answer (score 3):

Mike Honeychurch has provided a workaround [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-are-the-exact-guidelines-for-what-is-allowed-in-a-cdf) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions), using a fullscreen option for the embedded CDF.

In your case you would need to edit the html and change

```
cdf.embed('test.cdf', 843, 845);
```

to

```
cdf.embed('test.cdf', 843, 845,{fullscreen:'true'});
```